How to properly read and handle 'Amazon.BedrockAgentRuntime.Model.ResponseStream' in InvokeAgentResponse?
Current implementation
    public class AgentClient : IAgentClient
    {
        private readonly AmazonBedrockAgentRuntimeClient _client;
        private readonly BedrockSettings _settings;

        public AgentClient()
        {

            _settings = new BedrockSettings();

            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(_settings.AccessKeyId, _settings.SecretAccessKey);

            var config = new AmazonBedrockAgentRuntimeConfig
            {
                RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_settings.Region)
            };

            _client = new AmazonBedrockAgentRuntimeClient(credentials, config);
        }

        public async Task<ResponseStream> QueryAgentAsync(string sessionId, string inputText)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = new InvokeAgentRequest
                {
                    SessionId = sessionId,
                    AgentId = _settings.AgentId,
                    AgentAliasId = _settings.AgentAliasId,
                    InputText = inputText,
                    EnableTrace = true
                };

                var agentResponse = await _client.InvokeAgentAsync(request);

                if (agentResponse.Completion == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Completion is undefined in the response.");
                }

                var responseContent = agentResponse.Completion;
                Console.WriteLine("Agent Response Content: " + responseContent);

                return responseContent;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error invoking agent: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

output
Agent Response Content: Amazon.BedrockAgentRuntime.Model.ResponseStream
What I Tried:
I am using the Amazon Bedrock SDK to query an agent using InvokeAgentAsync. I successfully sent the request and received a response. However, when I attempt to access the agent's response, I get an object of type Amazon.BedrockAgentRuntime.Model.ResponseStream instead of a plain text or readable output.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
var agentResponse = await _client.InvokeAgentAsync(request);

if (agentResponse.Completion == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Completion is undefined.");
}

// Attempting to retrieve response content
return agentResponse.Completion.ToString();

This results in output like:
Agent Response Content: Amazon.BedrockAgentRuntime.Model.ResponseStream
I also inspected agentResponse.Completion, but I couldn't find a property like Text or Message containing the response content.

What I Expected:
I was expecting agentResponse.Completion to have a property or method that returns the agent's response as plain text (e.g., Text or Message). Alternatively, if ResponseStream is involved, I expected documentation or a clear method to process it and extract the text content.

In C# We need to serialize/deserialize the response object  with strongly typed POCO / DTO objects and get all the properties in the response.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/agents-lambda.html
In the link you will find a python sample where there is a direct json output shown which will not work the same in .net, java . So you create the POCO classes and serialize it make the request and vice versa while deserializing the response.
sample request class.
    public class BedrockAgentRequest
{
    public string MessageVersion { get; set; }
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
    public string InputText { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string ActionGroup { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SessionAttributes { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> PromptSessionAttributes { get; set; }
}

